# Can a web component have flexbox children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, web-component, custom-element

CSS Flexbox layout works as a parent-child relationship between elements. A parent element is set to `display: flex` and its children become flex children.

I'm looking for a clear answer on what's supposed to happen if a web component (or custom element) is set as a flex parent.  What are the flex children of a custom element, if any?  And, does the answer change based on whether shadow DOM is enabled or not.

In parent document:

```
<my-custom-element style="display: flex"></my-custom-element>
```

In custom element template:

```
<div style="flex: auto">A</div>
<div style="flex: auto">B</div>
<div style="flex: auto">C</div>
```

Comment: What conclusions have you drawn thus far yourself?

Comment: Perhaps you could put up a simple snippet showing the creation of the custom element as it's not completely clear to me what the problem is or how the two bits of code you have shown mesh together. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for info on how to put an example into your question.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: My conclusions are I have seen it work and was confused why it works, as it seemed to break encapsulation of the component.  I see now the encapsulation has certain openings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's check using both variants:

```js
customElements.define('custom-element-with-shadowroot', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = `
      <style>
        :host { display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 20px; height: 50px; width: 200px; }
        div { background-color: orange; }
      </style>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>      
    `;
  }
});

customElements.define('custom-element-without-shadowroot', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        custom-element-without-shadowroot { display: flex; flex-direction: row; gap: 20px; height: 50px; width: 200px; }
        div { background-color: orange; }
      </style>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>      
    `;
  }
});
```

```html
<custom-element-with-shadowroot></custom-element-with-shadowroot>
<hr>
<custom-element-without-shadowroot></custom-element-without-shadowroot>
```

As you can see, both with and without shadow DOM the custom element itself can act as a flex container. Please note that `:host` is only available with shadow DOM.